# Stop CI workflow when SonarQube finds some bugs or bad code style

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity

### sonarQube and teamcity relative question.

I want to use SonarQube into CI workflow which integrated by teamcity. I want to know how to stop the CI workflow when SonarQube finds some bugs or bad code style. Does a solution exist?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a [Quality Gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Gates), then look at adding the [Build Breaker plugin](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker)